# Is it safe to remove system gems after installing RVM and using gemsets?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Does anyone know if it's ok to uninstall all system gems after installing RVM and if I'm using only gemsets for each project?

I'd like to just get rid of some of the extra stuff lying around on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what OS you are on, but if you are on Mac OS, you need to exercise some care removing gems from the system.

Apple installs Ruby for their own use, not because they are benevolent and doing it as a convenience for the user. We can piggyback on that installed version, with awareness that we could break Apple's functionality.

Run `find /usr -type f -name '*.rb'` for a list of the Apple application code that relies on the pre-installed Ruby. Analyze those files to determine what gems are required.

Or, don't worry if the gems are there. A Ruby running under control of RVM won't see the gems used by /usr/bin/ruby so there is no chance of a conflict; That's the whole point of RVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any system gems, the only thing you have to check before removing them is to make sure not programs like textmate etc use the system ruby (as default) with some of the gems.

But just check the gem list and remove any unwanted gems, and add them if some functions doesn't work.

Terw

Comment: It isn't safe to assume you can change an OS installed language. It is often installed to supply functionality the OS provides, so, unless you have a good knowledge of the needs of that code, you're better off to leave it alone. Use RVM to install separate Rubies, or directly install them into /opt or /usr/local and leave the original unchanged.